# What species of mushroom is this?

Tags: species-identification, mycology

[image]

Growing up in Oregon I don't remember ever seeing these. There are different mushrooms growing all over my backyard right now, but these look way different than all the others and there was only a small cluster of them in the corner, which caught my eye. Searching online and trying to match pictures it keeps coming back to Psilocybe Semilanceata aka Liberty Caps, which apparently are hallucinogenic.  Like I said  I've never seen these before growing up in Oregon, so I'm curious as to what they really are. I tried to upload a better picture, but it was too big of a file, so hopefully this one is good enough. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Your mushroom is a bit old for identification I'm afraid. Try to take a picture when they are fresh and preferably at the place where they grow.